# Python grid Works at once and doesnt on the other

Tags: python

```
rows, cols = (rowSize, columnSize)  #creating 2d lists
grid = [[random.randint(10, 99) for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
```

WHen going through this for any value it works or gives an error of list index out of range

```
for i in range(0, cols-1):
    for j in range(0, rows-1):
        if random.randint(0, 10) == 0:
            grid[i][j] = ''
```

I tried to create a grid of rows and columns based on user input and this works for the same input sometimes and doesnt work for the same input another time. The error that pops is list index out of range. Please help me find the issue here

Comment: Your indexes are backwards. It should be `grid[j][i]`.

Comment: Also, `range()` is half-open on the right side, so you should not subtract one. Just use `range(columns)`, `range(rows)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if random.randint(0, 10) == 0:
            grid[i][j] = ''
```